# how to access made objects from the service

Tags: wpf, wcf, web-services, business-intelligence

I have a WCF service and a WPF application in my solution.

The application contains objects I made (customer, products etc), my windows and my business logic.

I need to retrieve a list of customers using the service but the service doesn't know what is a customer.

I CAN put all of my objects in both projects or reference one project from the other but that doesn't seem like the right way.

Any idea what should I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use data contract in your service like.

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember]
     public int CustomerID{ get; set; }    }

    [DataMember]
     public string CustomerName{ get; set; }    
}

public interface ICustomerService
{

    [OperationContract]
    List<Customer> GetAllCustomer();
}

 public Class CustomerService:ICustomerService
 {

    List<Customer> GetAllCustomer()
    {
           // write your own code to fill List<Customer> ans return it
    }
 }
```

Thanks

Ck Nitin (TinTin)

Comment: Thanks, I recalled something like that but wasn't sure. But do you know how do I access the customer class from my BI project? It doesn't appear to be in the client object.

Answer (score 0):

When will add the service reference of WCF or add the .dll in which WCF service is define in case if you are calling the WCF service from code using ServiceHost class, you can create the object for  this customer class and you can easily use it.

Thanks

Ck Nitin (TinTin)